# Is it possible to change a users Identifier on Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I'm using Firebase Authentication in a project of mine and I'm authenticating users by generating a token for them and having them sign in with that token. On the Firebase website, there is a list of all the users that you have using Firebase Authentication. Like so.

[image]

As you can see normally under the identifier column it shows the users email address. Since I'm signing in using a token it just shows dashes. I was wondering if there was a way to change this so that it showed the users username or something of that sort.

Comment: You can't change the identifier to be a username. This is not supported to begin with. Currently the identifier can be either: email, phone number or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the display of the Authentication dashboard.  If you have a feature request for some functionality that's not available, [please file one](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).