# Can Firebase Authentication Identifier be forced to be an obfuscated value?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

What I want to achieve is to have a completely obfuscated value in Firebase Authentication Identifier, which is to be used only to verify that a user is authenticated and get the correct UID to work against firestore.
No need for reset password or such features, because I would use an external identity provider (like Auth0), although user migration and preserving old data will be a thing to face eventually.
So ideally in Firebase Auth I would like to see something like:
Identifier: 9fh4h4gt (Auth0 UID)
User UID: dnv7824h024 (id used to link the user in firestore)

I know from several years old answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613251/is-it-possible-to-change-a-users-identifier-on-firebase-authentication) that it was not possible to have custom values in the Identifier field in Firebase Authentication, and I could not find any new statement contradicting that, therefore I ask again because after so many years (and a number of requests for this use case), the limitation might have been lifted.

I tried to get a token with only *openid* claim, without *email* and *profile*, but the Firebase Android SDK (*startActivityForSignInWithProvider*) hardcodes them apparently.
So I tried to use manual calls to authenticate and get the token from Auth0 first, but I always got one or the other issue, like MISSING_IDENTIFIER when directly using it with *signInWithCustomToken*, not valid nonce when using *signInWithCredential*, or some unspecified internal server error on Auth0 side when trying to use directly the *AuthenticationAPIClient.login*.

Comment: If you're using an external identity provider, consider [implementing a customer provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in Firebase for it. That way, you can use the Auth0 ID of the user as the UID in Firebase.

Comment: I already tried, but I am getting MISSING_IDENTIFIER. I assumed it is missing it in Firebase and thus refuses to authenticate, rather than missing some info in the passed token. Also, the documentation there seems to expect only Admin SDK or a JWT library to use a Google service account to create the custom token, which is not the case when getting the token from Auth0.

Comment: To use the Auth0 token in Firebase you'll need to mint a Firebase ID token based on the information in the Auth0 token, and then sign the user into Firebase with that. ---


If you tried to generate a custom token, then please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @fra I elaborated a bit more the question for now, and I am going to try what you suggested (I was hoping I could get away without a server in between).
If I understood correctly, this flow should work: client logs in and gets token from Auth0, sends that token to the server to recreate a new token signed with Google service account having the desired identifier instead of email, then send it to Firebase for final authentication.

Comment: Yup, that sounds right.

Comment: Alright, so I did not achieve what I was initially looking for (my custom values to appear in the Identifier field), but figuring out that field seems to be actually just eye candy with no requirement to be something specific, while UID is, I could live with dashes as Identifiers and my chosen values as UID with a minted JWT on a Firebase function, as suggested by @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

> I know from several years old answers like this that it was not possible to have custom values in the Identifier field in Firebase Authentication, and I could not find any new statement contradicting that, therefore I ask again because after so many years (and a number of requests for this use case), the limitation might have been lifted.

No, it is still not possible to change (obfuscate) the value of the UID in the Firebase Authentication once is generated. So you can continue to file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) or suggest it on [uservoice](https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general).

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I am trying a more articulate solution with what has been proposed above with custom tokens. Then we will know which answer is correct :)

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an external identity provider, consider [implementing a customer provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in Firebase for it. That way, you can use the Auth0 ID of the user as the UID in Firebase.

To use the Auth0 token in Firebase you'll need to mint a Firebase ID token based on the information in the Auth0 token, and then sign the user into Firebase with that.